# jQuery resizable div unwanted behaviour with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a web application, and I need to have a panel on the right side of the page capable of being resized. I've accomplished that by using jQuery UI. But my app also needs to use Bootstrap, and I think that's the problem: when Itry to resize it, it moves a bit to the left. I don't want this effect can somebody help me please?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23280/)

The box to be resized is the red one from right to left.

```
$('.move').resizable({handles: 'w'});
```

Comment: For me its ok..its not moving to left..what is the issue?

Comment: Ok, I had the wrong one, try the fiddle now please.

Comment: For me its same. Moving to right when resizing small.

Comment: @LeonardoChirivì Ok now I see it.

Comment: Maybe I've said that wrong, I mean resize the red box width, not the browser?

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek  Yeah, the whole box just moves before being resized right?

Comment: @LeonardoChirivì Yes on resize the red box gets smaller on the bottom and right side each time.

Comment: sorry still not able to see the issue. And bdw you have wrong height for red div. Use vh as you used for parent div.

Comment: @Leothelion Are you looking at the updated fiddle?

Comment: yes @SpencerWieczorek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resizable-function fails with this css property `box-sizing:border-box` as while resizing it forgets the padding and this property merges padding to width.

So while resizing it reduces the padding each time you start resizing and bootstrap css use this property.

Use this `box-sizing:content-box`

```
.move{
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 5px solid #f00;   
  margin-right: 0;
  box-sizing:content-box
}
```

This will overwrite default bootstrap css on this element and resizable function will work fine.

See fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23283/